# jQuery : should i check for visibility before hiding an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it best practice to check if an element is visible before hiding it, or is ok just to hide it? What are the benefits either way?

In the example below, the first checks for visibility before hiding the `.foo` element...

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.menu').fadeToggle();
    if($('.foo').is(':visible')){
        $('.foo').fadeOut();
    };
});
```

or

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.menu').fadeToggle();
    $('.foo').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Why would you check ? jQuery's main benefit is to bring concision and readability to your code, don't clutter it without reason.

Comment: Skip the `if`, `fadeOut` already check it for you.

Comment: Some, but not all, jQuery transition methods will check the current state, so it depends on which transitions you use.

Comment: Toggle should do this for you. If it's hidden it will show, if it's visible it will hide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a note from [**jQuery's .fadeOut() specs**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/):

> **Note:** To avoid unnecessary DOM manipulation, .fadeOut() will not hide an element that is already considered hidden.

So, relax... There's nothing wrong with hiding an element that's already hidden. JQuery will check it for you.

Comment: thanks, i was looking at the source, and did not specifically see a check for this. I guess i should rtfm.