# should i check for visibility before hiding an element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

should I  check  the visibility of the element before hiding it?

There is  very  similar  question  for  jquery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426195/jquery-should-i-check-for-visibility-before-hiding-an-element/%22here%22) . But  when I'm using clear javascript does it make a  difference? is the if statement redundant?

```
var loader = document.getElementById('loader');

function hideLoader() {
 if (loader.style.visibility === 'visible') {
  loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
}
```

Comment: There should not be any problem if you directly set the visibility to hidden. Are you getting any error for the same?

Comment: i think there is no worry to check visibility before hiding its nice practice

Comment: No, there is no  error, still I  was wondering what would  be a good thing to do in this case

Comment: If you  just want to hide, no need to check the existing visibility. DOnly this line is enough inside the body : loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to do it. Just set desired visiblity to hidden and save your browser some 'if' calculations.